# Set Dynamic x-axis range in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

The following setting sets the x-axis range on Highcharts to the past hour:

```
xAxis: {
    min: new Date().setHours(new Date().getHours() - 1), // last hour
    max: new Date().getTime()),                          // now
},
```

However more data points are added every few seconds. How can you make the x-axis dynamic such that the scale updates with new data points, showing only the past hour?

Answer (score 5):

When adding your points dynamically you could update the x-axis at the same time using `Axis.setExtremes` ([API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes)). For example like this:

```
// Add new (random) point
chart.series[0].addPoint(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));

// Update x-axis range
chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(new Date().getTime(), new Date().setHours(new Date().getHours()+1));
```

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgyuypkn/) for a similar demonstration.

Answer (score 3):

Have you look into Highstock? http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo . Maybe it's more adapted for what you are doing

But on Highchart you can update the min max like this :

```
chart.xAxis[0].update({
    min: new Date().getTime(),
    max: new Date().setHours(new Date().getHours()-1),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1) it looks like you have it backwards (max should be 'now', min should b -1 hour)

2) what is the actual problem? What is not working?

If you set the min/max appropriately, only data within the min and max will be displayed.

You should also only send data to the chart that is within the time frame that you want to display. Otherwise you'll end up sending a ton of data that isn't needed.

Look at the 'shift' property of the addPoint() method:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.addPoint

Look also at the setData() method:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData